# problem with pagination in function based view in django

Tags: django, pagination

can’t understand how to use pagination in this kind of function.

```
def product_list(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)

    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        products = products.filter(category=category)
    return render(request,
                  'shop/product/list.html',
                  {'category': category,
                   'categories': categories,
                   'products': products,
                   })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Django `Paginator` as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view).

For example, based on your view, you will have something like this:

```py
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

def product_list(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)

    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        products = products.filter(category=category)

    # Create a paginator to split your products queryset
    paginator = Paginator(products, 25)  # Show 25 products per page
    # Get the current page number
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    # Get the current slice (page) of products
    products = paginator.get_page(page)

    return render(request,
                  'shop/product/list.html',
                  {'category': category,
                   'categories': categories,
                   'products': products,
                   })
```

Check the link above to see how to use the paginator inside your template, for example to create links to the previous/following pages.

Answer (score -1):

Pagination is only available in class based views.  It works by having a method [paginate_queryset](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.list/ListView/#paginate_queryset).

A List view has a [`get`](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.list/ListView/#get) method, which in turn calls [`get_context_data`](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.list/ListView/#get_context_data), and that then calls the paginate queryset method.

If you want to do this in a FBV, you need to implement similar logic.